# Accessing object in models parent

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am trying to call a function that is inside my Database class but I can't seem to get it right.

My Model class calls Database and assigns it to a variable:

```
class Model {

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->db = NULL;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to call it from:

```
class User extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function userExists($username) {
        return $this->model->db->select('users', 'id', 'email LIKE ?', array($username));
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Manager 2014\controllers\User.php on line 10
```

My Database class is:

```
class Database extends PDO {

    function __construct($user = 'root', $pass = '', $database = 'xxx', $host = 'localhost') {
        try {
            parent::__construct('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, FALSE);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, FALSE);
            $this->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            Database::handleDbError($e);
        }
    }

    public function select($table, $cols, $where = null, $whereVals = null, $order = null) {
        if ($this->tableExists($table)) {
            $PDOParams = array();
            $SQL = 'SELECT ' . $cols . ' FROM ' . $table;
            if ($where) {
                $SQL .= ' WHERE ' . $where;
            }
            if ($whereVals) {

            }
            if ($order) {
                $SQL .= 'ORDER BY ' . $order;
            }
            return $SQL;
        } else {

        }
    }

    public function tableExists($table) {
        $r = $this->PDO->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE ?");
        $r->execute(array($table));
        return $r->rowCount();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

If I:

```
print_r(get_class_vars ('UserModel'));
```

From the User class I get:

```
Array( [db] => )
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because that is being assigned in Model in the constructor that is being called when UserModel is called.

---

Instead of select() in my Database class, I now have the following in my main Model class:

```
public function get($primaryKeyId) {
    $table = str_replace('model', '', strtolower(get_called_class()));
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = ?";
    $r = $this->db->prepare($SQL);
    $r->execute(array($primaryKeyId));
    return $r->fetch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many essential flaws with your implementation.

1. First and foremost, **get rid of `select()` function**

   - it's awfully insecure, allowing raw variables into query
   - it's fantastically inflexible, allowing only silly sandbox queries
   - it makes unreadable gibberish out of neat almost natural English of SQL
2. Second, do not create anew DB instance every time you invoke a class. Even simple app will kill your db server with that much number of connects.

   - **pass db as a parameter into constructor instead**
3. As it seems from your comment, errorhandler method doesn't handle anything which makes it evil

   - if you have no idea how to handle an error - just let it go. Get rid of this try/catch thingy completely

Comment: Previously I was creating get, set, create and delete functions in all my models, even if I just needed to do simple selects. It's why I came up with a global select function to save on creating lots of get functions in my models. Why would it be insecure (I intended to finish it where it would use PDO)?

Comment: 1. PDO is not a magic chant that makes all your SQL secure in a puff of smoke. you should never add even a single variable into query - only then it will be safe. 2. **It's your prototype model** should contain get, set, create and delete functions. And get() one should be different from your current select(), allowing only primary key lookup from the predefined table name variable.

Comment: So if they are defined in my master Model class, I would call get from say UserModel by: $this->get($column, $table, $primaryKeyId); ?

Comment: @imperium2335 yes, exactly. that's what this `extends` thingy actually for. But it should be rather $this->get($primaryKeyId); as Model should already know the table name and return full row instead of single column

Comment: But if I don't declare which columns to fetch isn't it inefficient to bring back everything if I only needed one column?

Comment: that's scary tale for children. If you store something really big in the same table - then you are already did something wrong. Yet with sanely designed table and single row select it scarcely could be a problem.

Comment: So, as a **general purpose get()** you apparently have to use *, to make this method **secure** and convenient. In case of such a model where * would be improper you have to **rewrite** this method in a child class.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. So something like in my new edit right?

Comment: yes. and remember that if you will need some other logic in some particular Model (say, find by email instead of primary key) you have to write a distinct method called `findByEmail()` in that Model, with raw SQL in it

Answer (score 0):

The database object in your model needs to be public so it can be accessed outside of the Model class.

```
class Model {

    public $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->db = NULL;
    }

}
```

See [object visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) for details on the difference between public, protected, and private.

Comment: @wanasten I thought non declared variables in a class context defaulted to public anyway? It didn't work anyway :(

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) isn't clear if undeclared class properties are pubic, it was the one thing I noticed. Are you sure you've included the file that contains the Model class? If you add a test public function within the Model class can you access that function?

Comment: Yes, any function or property I create in the Model class I can call.

Answer (score 0):

I had just done a custom build of AMP and forgot to enable mysql PDO extension...That's why the DB parameter was empty *FACEPALM*.